# css line-height and font-size behavior

Tags: html, ckeditor, font-size, css

I am trying to figure out why this piece of code (http://jsfiddle.net/konark/5JuJc/) renders different in CkEditor (as well as JSFiddle) and any web browser. 
I need line-height and font-size under separate span tags. The order of span tags does not alter the rendered text in web browser. However, it does alter the results in CKEditor (JSFiddle as well).

I realize that CkEditor/JSFiddle wraps up the code in iframe, but I am unable to find a concrete reason for the difference in behavior.

Here are two pieces I am trying to test in browser and JSFiddle:

```
<body> 
  <span style="line-height:8pt;">
    <span style="font-size:34pt;">
      <span style="color:#008000">This is a sample text. It will change its appearance based on your style selections.
      </span>
    </span>
  </span>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<span style="font-size:34pt;">
  <span style="line-height:8pt;">
    <span style="color:#008000">This is a sample text. It will change its appearance based on your style selections
    </span>
  </span>
</span>
```

Any thoughts much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: 1. Why don't you use CSS instead of inline style?
2. In your second example, the outmost SPAN wrap line-height doesn't get a value so a default value of 100% is applied (user agent style sheet). That's why the line-height looks like 34pt.

Comment: What is the difference you are talking about?

Comment: In the second sallad of `span` tags, the outmost `span` element has the initial value of `normal` for `line-height`; its exact meaning is font- and browser-dependent. But this happens both in jsfiddle and when testing the code as such in a browser.

Comment: [Here is the screenshot comparison of the code](http://imgur.com/bhi4xln). Left one shows the text in JSFiddle with its respective output and the right screenshot shows the same text in google chrome.
@Godinall : I am trying to capture CKeditor button events and create inline styles on the fly which is sent to some other system for processing. The other system restricts us to use just span with styles. Also I understand the line-height looks like 34 pt, but I am curious why does it behaves differently in web browser.
Jukka: I have linked the screenshot for reference.